# How to assign random colors to a gameObject in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 3 colors ( Red, Green, and Yellow ), I want to assign random colors from these 3 colors to my Ball every time when My game starts or restarts after gameOver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the colors in the list and select them in the inspector.

```
public List<Color> Colors = new List<Color>();

private void ChangeColor()
{
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Colors[Random.Range(0, Colors.Count)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list or array with the colors, then use random.range() accordingly on that array in the Start method (or a custom method if you restart manually.)
If every color should be guaranteed unique, use the singleton pattern to keep a common instance of that colors list and remove the used color every time it's taken.